# How to detect if a sheet has been deleted

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anybody have any insight on how to detect when a user deletes a sheet?

I have combed through all the documentation of Apps Script Triggers and cannot figure out how to detect sheet deletion. This seems so simple, surely there is a way.

Comment: I think you can do through Activity API which I think is now part of Drive API

Comment: Try catch perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the detect *if* a sheet has been deleted, you can use an [on change installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) check if the type is `REMOVE_GRID`:

```
function detectDeletion(e) {
    if (e.changeType === 'REMOVE_GRID') {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Sheet deleted!');
    }
}
```